# Only have one instance of an Azure Function?

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I can't find any documentation on how to force an Azure Function v4 into a singleton, so as the function app scales out (for reasons), one of the functions doesn't scale out.

My function is a TIMER TRIGGER, in a v4 .NET6.0 ISOLATED Azure function.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/announcing-azure-functions-4-0-public-preview-with-net-6-support/ba-p/2772098 - this blog post will helps you to create .net 6 azure function v4 !

Comment: Thanks you for the link .. but that's not answering my question. That link is just about general stuff with .NET 6 + AzFunc. I'm looking for a more detailed, direct answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio?tpivots=programming-runtime-functions-v4) shows direct creation of .net 6 in Azure functions v4 in Visual Studio and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?pivots=programming-runtime-functions-v4&tabs=in-process) is for working with VS code to the same .Net 6 Azure Functions V4 and this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?pivots=programming-runtime-functions-v4&tabs=azure-cli,in-process) helps you to work with Azure Functions v4 and .Net Core 6 through the command line.

> I can't find any documentation on how to force an Azure Function v4 into a singleton, so as the function app scales out (for reasons), one of the functions doesn't scale out.

> If a function app scales out to multiple instances, only a single instance of a timer-triggered function is run across all instances. It will not trigger again if there is an outstanding invocation is still running.

Please refer this [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#scale-out) for more details and this [GitHub thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/45561/can-a-timed-azure-function-run-multiple-instances.html).

Answer (score 7):

Even if your Function App scales out the timer trigger will only run on a single instance.

> If a function app scales out to multiple instances, only a single instance of a timer-triggered function is run across all instances. It will not trigger again if there is an outstanding invocation is still running.

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#scale-out)

**edit** new quote:

> The timer trigger uses a storage lock to ensure that there is only one timer instance when a function app scales out to multiple instances. If two function apps share the same identifying configuration and each uses a timer trigger, only one timer runs.

**edit** newer quote:

> If a function app scales out to multiple instances, only a single instance of a timer-triggered function is run across all instances. It will not trigger again if there is an outstanding invocation is still running.

Comment: Link is not legit/valid?

Comment: Fixed the link @Pure.Krome